# Send email to user if their role is changed to Author

Tags: users, user-roles

I would like an email to be sent to the user when their role is changed to Author.

The code below sends an email when a user's role is changed to any role, but I would like it only to send if the role is changed to 'Author'.

```
function user_role_update( $user_id, $new_role ) {
    $site_url  = get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' );
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $to        = $user_info->user_email;
    $subject   = 'Role changed: ' . $site_url . '';
    $message   = 'Hello ' . $user_info->display_name . ' your role has changed on ' . $site_url . ', congratulations you are now an ' . $new_role;
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'user_role_update', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the value of `$new_role` before sending the email, if it isn't author then do nothing

```
function user_role_update( $user_id, $new_role ) {
    if ( $new_role == 'author' ) {
            $site_url  = get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' );
            $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
            $to        = $user_info->user_email;
            $subject   = 'Role changed: ' . $site_url . '';
            $message   = 'Hello ' . $user_info->display_name . ' your role has changed on ' . $site_url . ', congratulations you are now an ' . $new_role;
            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
    }
}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'user_role_update', 10, 2 );
```